# Hide passwords that are in the .js file

Tags: javascript, email, password-protection

I have a js file that sends emails like this:

```
Email.send ({
             Host: "smtp.gmail.com",
             Username: "mymail",
             Password: "mypassword",
             To: 'mymail',
             From: `$ {email}`,
             Subject: `Site, $ {name} invite a message`,
             Body: `$ {body} <br> $ {tel}`,
         })
         .then (function (message) {
             alert ("mail sent successfully")
         });
```

But my password is hardcode if someone inspect the code, can see it, how can I hide it?

Comment: _"...how can I hide it?"_ - Don't send mails that way.

Comment: @Andreas How can I send emails?

Comment: That's a job for your server.

Comment: @Andreas And how can I get him to receive information from my website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't do it this way as far as this code is not running on node.js server-side.

Sending emails should be done on the server-side, dunno which language you are using
so I'm going to paste below a list of useful classes from various frameworks/languages.

1. PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php
2. JAVA (Spring): https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mail.html
3. C# (ASP.NET): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/11-adding-email-to-your-web-site

And remember, never ever store passwords in plain text.

Comment: This project of mine is not for any company or client, even so I will have to develop a server?

Comment: You can run server-side via various tools like xampp

Comment: Okay, I think I'll do it

Answer (score 0):

How I resolved:
I used the google forms system.
I created a form with the fields I needed and incorporated it with a `<iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

So the real question here, which everyone apparently failed to address, is how to inject sensitive data into source code that shouldn't be saved with said data inside. There's several approaches, the most common one are environment variables.

You can run your node script with `EMAIL_PW=abcd1234 node myscript.js` and then access this value with `process.env.EMAIL_PW`.

Comment: I'm not using the `node`